# Resident Evil Code Veronica X - Clement A

Tags: resident-evil-1996

I have looked everywhere and I can't find it. I found already Clement E and I don't remember where to find Clement A. I have everything else in this Chris part, any help?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [website](http://www.evilresource.com/resident-evil-code-veronica/items/clement-alpha)

> Weapon Repair Shop - Military Training Facility B1
>
> After the fight with Nosferatu and playing as Chris. On the shelves next to the workbench

[image]

Comment: Damn, I was in that right a couple of times and could not see it. Thanks, man!